# Past participle of the verb 'irrompere'

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-participle

I can't figure out the past participle of the verb '**irrompere**': it seems to be a compound form of the verb '**rompere**', past participle of which is '**rotto**', but '*irrotto*' sounds very strange to me. Is this some kind of *irregular* verb?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is doesn't show research effort at all. See: http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/21/should-we-admit-easily-answerable-questions/72#72

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: IMHO, this question "shows research" for a beginner. He has studied the past participle, rotto for rompere, and reasonably wonders why irrotto doesn't sound right. A highly ranked answerer confirmed that the "beginner's hunch" was right, said that irrotto was technically correct but not used much (perhaps because it sounds bad), and offered alternatives, thereby answering the beginner's (reasonable) question. It was actually a lot more subtle than appears at first glance, and was not just a "simple" translation question.

Comment: I like your question because it is a fairly subtle one for a beginner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lo Zingarelli reports that the past participle of *irrompere* is *irrotto* and says that other compound tenses are rarely used.

> [image: screenshot]

[Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/irrompere/) says that past participle and compound tenses are not used.

I would understand *irrotto*, since it recalls the past participle of similar verbs like *corrompere* (*corrotto*), *rompere* (*rotto*).

Personally, instead of saying *la polizia è irrotta nel locale, bloccando ed arrestando quattro malviventi*, I would say *la polizia ha fatto irruzione nel locale, bloccando ed arrestando quattro malviventi*.

Answer (score 6):

Trattasi di verbo difettivo, dunque privo del participio passato e di conseguenza dei tempi composti.

Vedere la voce ["Irrompere" su Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/irrompere/) per confronto.

Questo in teoria, in pratica però *irrotto* si usa all'occorrenza.

Vedere per questo [il risultato da Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=irrotto&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,irrotto;,c0).

Comment: Never heard "irrotto" even in practice; by the way, often you replace all the composite forms with an appropriate conjugation of "fare irruzione" (especially in police context).

Answer (score 1):

It's irregular, you can use `aver fatto irruzione` if you need to use it with past.

Irrotto doesn't exist (we are still talking about a language, tomorrow irrotto can be perfectly correct).